# Plotting coefficients from multiple regression models with plot_coefs /plot_summs, maximum number?

Tags: r, plot, regression, coefficients

I run 15 different regression models (it is basically the same regression with the same variables, just different years) and plot the coefficents using plot_coefs.

In the plot, however, coefficents are only displayed for the first 12 of the 15 models. The legend on the other hand shows all models.

My command is:

```
cdu_1965b <- glm(cduwahl ~  alter + bildung + mann + konfessi 
                 , data = Wahl1965, family = "binomial")

cdu_1969b <- glm(cduwahl ~  alter + bildung + mann + konfessi 
                 , data = Wahl1969, family = "binomial")
```

.... (same for other 13 models)

```
library(jtools)
plot_coefs (cdu_1965b,cdu_1969b, ...other models..., colors = "Rainbow", omit.coefs = c("(Intercept)", "altermittel", "alteralt", "bildunghoch", "bildungmittel", "bildungalt", "mann"))
```

Is there a maximum number that can be plotted?

Thank you!

What else could I try?

Comment: Hi @JohannesH, welcome to SO! Please make sure you note any non-base R packages you're using; it seems this might be about the `plot_coef` function you're using. Is it this one? https://jtools.jacob-long.com/reference/plot_summs.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm sorry, I didn't know as I'm new SO.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be because `plot_coefs` only has 12 different shapes.

If you set `point.shape = F` all models should appear.

##### 13th model missing with point.shape

```
library(jtools)

lm1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars)

plot_coefs(lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, 
           colors = "Rainbow", 
           omit.coefs = c("(Intercept)", "altermittel", "alteralt", 
                          "bildunghoch", "bildungmittel", "bildungalt", "mann"))
```

[image]

##### But appears without point.shape

```
plot_coefs(lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1, 
           colors = "Rainbow", point.shape = F,
           omit.coefs = c("(Intercept)", "altermittel", "alteralt", 
                          "bildunghoch", "bildungmittel", "bildungalt", "mann"))
```

[image]